# How to keep editor in sync with directory structure in visual studio mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio, visual-studio-mac

This is a simple question but it annoys me since the update of visual studio for mac. I currently run the version 7.1 of Visual Studio for Mac Community..

Since the update I can't keep in sync the directory structure (on the left) with the file I edit (on the right). So when I switch from a class to another I do not know where the class is located in the hierarchy.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: I haven't used Visual Studio for the Mac, but on WIndows there's a button that looks like two arrows in the solution explorer that will find the current document in the solution. There's is a key command for it as well. I've also seen some addons that keep it in sync, although in my experience they make things slow..

Comment: Unable to reproduce this with VS for Mac 7.1. The file selected in the Solution window is highlighted based on the currently active file selected in the text editor. Can you provide some steps to reproduce this problem?

Comment: There were no specific step. I solved the problem by rebooting my mac. I thought it was reserved to windows. I think something was not working correctly right after the upgrade of visual studio. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Rebooting Mac didn't solve this problem.  It's really annoying.

Comment: I searched Microsoft Visual Studio developer community website and it sounds like tens of times people have reported this same bug and every time the coordinators have closed the case as vague or low priority!  Why is that potentially thousands of developers are affected by this and every single time they ignore to fix it?